# Having problem splitting a sting around the newline character

Tags: perl, io, newline

Here is another one of these weird things. I have this code and a file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "test.txt";
my @arr; 

open (LOGFILE, $file);
while (my $line = <LOGFILE>)     
{ 
    #print $line;
    @arr = split("\n", $line);
}   
close LOGFILE;

print $arr[1];
```

test.txt contains

> \ntest1 \ntest2 \ntest3

Here is the error I get:

> Use of uninitialized value in print at
>   test.pl line 15.

Did anyone encounter a similar problem in the past?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`split` takes a regex (I believe your string is coerced into a regex).  Maybe something like `split(/\\n/, $line)`?

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 my $file = "test.txt";
 my @arr;

 open (LOGFILE, $file);
 while (my $line = <LOGFILE>)
 {
   print $line;
   @arr = split(/\\n/, $line);
 }
 close LOGFILE;

 print $arr[1];
```

Comment: @seaworthy, i'm including the whole file in my response now because it is working for me (output: test1)

Comment: thanks for your help it works, had to use /\\n/ instead of "\\n".

Comment: @seaworthy.  np.  if you wanted to use quotes (not recommended since `split` really only deals with regexes), you'd have to do double your backslashes due to the way backslashes are handled in a string ("\\\\n" would do the trick).

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
@arr = split /\Q\n/, $line;
```